# Running shell script from terminal works but doesn't work when running from PHP shell_exec

Tags: php, shell, centos7

I've just started with shell scripts a week ago so please be easy on me. When I run `create.sh` from the terminal, everything works great as expected. However when I execute the same script `create.sh` from `create.php` it doesn't work.

I'm executing my PHP script from the web browser by visiting the URL: `http://192.168.8.108:8083/create.php`

***create.php*** – This file is responsible for running the `create.sh` file

```
echo shell_exec('/usr/local/panel/bin/create.sh');
```

***create.sh*** – This file creates a directory under `/var/www`. 
The permission

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example.com
```

- **Owner**: root **Access**: Read and Write
- **Group**: root **Access**: Read-only
- **Public**: **Access**: Read-only

Comment: Possibly because environment will be different when shell script is executed from shell_exec()

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara any tutorials that you can give. I'm very new to this and have no idea what you just said about environment.

Comment: How do you execute `create.php`? `sudo php create.php` ?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara I'm executing it from web browser by visiting `http://192.168.8.108:8083/create.php

Comment: what user used to execute `create.php`?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara apache

Comment: Then you need to make sure `apache` user has write access to `/var/www`

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara Yes, you are right. Please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that user who run php script has correct permission. If script `create.php` run as `apache` then you need to make sure `apache` user has write access to `/var/www` directory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. I've learnt something new.